# Is it possible to have audio follow window across multiple displays

Tags: display, audio

I'm using multiple monitors and would like to have the audio from any particular app window come from the speakers associated with the display where the app window is shown.

Anyone know of a solution?

This is iMac Pro or MacBook Pro running Mojave. It would be any application that produces sound. I would like the sound directed to the display upon which the app's window is displayed.

Comment: what is the App ?  on what Mac, what OSX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not possible.**

Apple does not "link" audio devices and video devices in any way.  As far as macOS is concerned, you have discrete audio devices and discrete video (display) devices.  In fact, you cannot even [control audio from a Mac connected via HDMI or DisplayPort](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336751/119271)

Some Apps (i.e. [Vox Music Player](https://vox.rocks/)) allows you to select a different audio device from the default.  If the App you're using (Safari for example) is playing a YouTube video, it would have to be able to be "aware" of the other audio devices (it's not).

Your app would not only have to be aware of the additional audio devices but the location of it's Window in relation to the monitor it's connected to.  It's highly unlikely app programmers would include that functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It was my hope that the discrete audio devices would make it easier at the OS level to make this possible. I would think the OS is aware of what windows are playing audio, should be aware of the display upon which the window is shown and then allow a configuration such that audio from windows shown on a particular display would be directed to an identified, discrete, audio device; in my case that particular display or another device. I could see this as an OS-level configuration option. My other hope was that an already existing audio-routing app had this capability.