# Can I use my keyboard to control the volume of speakers connected to my macbook by a usb c hub?

Tags: audio, usb, sound-volume, peripheral

I found out that I can't control the volume of speakers connected to my monitor via HDMI using volume controls in the OS. There are countless questions about this issue, the most upvoted one being [How do I control Macbook volume when a DP display is connected?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/336750/how-do-i-control-macbook-volume-when-a-dp-display-is-connected).

However there are some USB C hubs for sale that include a 3.5mm audio port. I was thinking that if I buy one of these I would be able to control the volume of speakers through the OS. However in one of the reviews for one of the hubs ([this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B091KKB74Y)), someone mentioned that they were unable to control the volume using the OS. So does this mean all USB C hubs also have this issue? I could only find discussions concerning HDMI or DisplayPort.

The reason for all of this is I want to easily control my volume using my keyboard and I also want to limit the number of cables I have connected to my MacBook as much as possible.

P.S. I know there are software solutions. I need to avoid a software solution and just need a firm "yes" or "no, because etc.."

Answer (score 0):

According to the Amazon listing, the 3.5mm port is an ***In/Out AUX*** port; you should be able to control volume with this port.

[image]

The difference between this device and HDMI/DisplayPort connections is that since it has an “in” port, it must be a USB audio device and is not using the video signals to embed audio.  Since it is a discrete audio device, you will be able to control the volume.

Granted, this is based off the item description so, the standard disclaimer applies: YMMV.