# How to control sound of connected external monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, audio

I know this is not natively supported in macOS, but I think it could be easily solved by an app that does the following:

- Set the sound volume on the external monitor to a desired maximum level.
- The app is a **global** volume slider for all the sounds generated by the MacBook.
- You can use the app to easily control the sound volume of the external monitor.

Is there an app that does exactly this?

**EDIT:**

I tried SoundFlower but it was buggy and caused problems with other sound extensions. I discovered [Sound Control](https://staticz.com/soundcontrol/) which exactly does what I want. Even the built in macOS sound control works.

Answer (score 5):

A popular 3rd party software that lets you control the volume of a connected external display is [Soundflower](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower). It is a kernel extension.

The installer for the latest signed version with support for macOS Mojave can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/tag/2.0b2). If you use Homebrew, you can also install install it by running the command:

`brew cask install soundflower`

Since it is a kernel extension, you'll need to enable it by going to System Preferences app → Security & Privacy → General and click on **Allow**.

[image]

[image]

Next, you'll need to download and install the [SoundflowerBed](https://github.com/mLupine/SoundflowerBed/releases/tag/2.0.0-release) utility. It is the user facing macOS app that will let you control the audio. To install using Homebrew, run the following command:

`brew cask install soundflowerbed`

You are all set up now. Simply launch the SoundflowerBed app from Launchpad. It is a Menu bar app. Click on the app icon in the Menu bar and select DisplayPort, Thunderbolt or HDMI as the output in the (2ch) list.

[image]

Now, click the volume icon in the Menu bar and choose Soundflower(2ch). You can also make this selection in the Sound System Preference pane.

[image]

Now, you should be easily able to control the volume of your external display from your MacBook.

**Note**: Parts of this answer have been taken from the recently published [article](https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/use-mac-volume-keys-adjust-monitor-audio/) on MacRumors.

Comment: Great! Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. Does it support custom keyboard shortcuts and a hud display like the original mac sound control?

Comment: Well I just went through the Mac Rumours thread. It seems like it wasn't updated since 2014. Some users don't suggest installing it because it messed up their audio.

Comment: @MJQZ1347 The SoundflowerBed utility is not updated for a while, but the kernel extension has been updated to work with macOS Mojave.

Comment: I was not able to install it. The installation failed even though I did everything like described (incl. ctrl + left clicking for opening the .pkg). Using homebrew did not work, either.

Comment: This instruction helped: https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower-Original/issues/79#issuecomment-422907975 Step 2 and 3 are crucial.

Comment: BTW: Is there a way to get rid off SoundFlowerBed? I only need it once for selecting the output device. But closing it will make you lose the configuration. Any terminal commands for this?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 If you wish to completely remove `soundflowerbed` from system, you can do so by running `brew cask zap soundflowerbed`.

Comment: What I meant was: What do I need SoundFlowerBed for? Seemingly only for selecting the output device which I don't change that often. But closing SoundFlowerBed also resets the output device. So SoundFlowerBed needs to be running in the background. Is there a way to set the output device via terminal?

Comment: @MJQZ1347 Sorry I have no idea (I am travelling currently and do not have access to an external display too).

Comment: I have successfully installed for Catalina with this updated repo : https://github.com/anastasiuspernat/SoundflowerBed